# scp command creating a copy in the remote machine itself

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

The command I am using to copy a file from remote to my local machine is as follows:

```
scp root@IP_OF_MY_REMOTE_MACHINE:/home/sqldump.sql ~
```

So I am copying from /home directory of remote machine to my local machine home directory but what i get is a file copied in the remote machine's home directory.

Where I am going wrong ?

I know it must be silly mistake. But any help will be thankfully received.

Comment: Not sure about this but try `~/` instead of `~`.

Comment: No terdon still not finished but atleast this problem is removed where a file by my local username was created and that sqldump.sql was copied into that.

Comment: What's the full path of your home directory? Does it contain any non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: full path of my home directory is /home/babloo. It does n't have any non-alphanumeric charatcers.

Comment: Does this happen as well if you use the full path, i.e., `/home/babloo` instead of `~`?

Comment: Yes. Then it creates a file named babloo in the remote machine itself and copies the content of sqldump.sql into that newly created file.

Comment: Check you command again. Is there a `:` after the `~`? In which case you are instructing scp to do a remote to remote copy. If that is not the case check if scp is aliassed somehow.

Comment: To put all these suggestions together, what happens if you do `\scp root@IP_OF_MY_REMOTE_MACHINE:/home/sqldump.sql /home/babloo/`?

Comment: terdon thanks but still it doesn't copies to my home folder though the message of copy progress is displayed ie
          sqldump.sql   100%   40KB  40.0KB/s   00:00

this above is showed but no copy is availale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to all. Human Stupidity is unbounded, I am a living example of that. I typed command correctly, but it was not in the machine where it should have been typed.

The above command should be typed at the local machine terminal and then it would fetch the copy of the required file from remote machine to the local machine.
So the command makes sense only if typed at the local machine terminal:-

```
scp root@IP_OF_MY_REMOTE_MACHINE:/home/sqldump.sql ~/
```

and then it would copy from the server machine to the local machine.
Once again sorry to all esteemed members, especially terdon, Hennes,Dennis and Pete Cornell.But thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file name in target, like this:

scp root@IP_OF_MY_REMOTE_MACHINE:/home/sqldump.sql ~/sqldump.sql

Comment: It didn't work Pete Cornell. Thanks though.

Comment: Ssh into the remote system and verify the file path. The one you have, /home/sqldump.sql looks unusual.  It's more likely to be in your home directory, /home/[username]/sqldump.sql. You could also try rsync in the same manner, and verify that root is permitted ssh access.